# How to extend a Class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have my own Object, and I'd like to extend it, saving data from a person and adding new info.

So the code would be:

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

but when I try to init it and add the new value:

```
Person person = new Person("Paul", "Catch");
Student student = (Person)person;
student.code = "1234";
```

I got `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MyLayer.Person' to type 'Student'.`

Am I missing some point?

**EDIT**: maybe I wrong putting that Person class. You must suppose it become from a DB as object, such as `Person person = new MyPersons().First();`

So I won't to populate the new one with properties one by one, just extend one property thanks to the new object that extend the old one.

Comment: Show us `Person` class..

Comment: Please show the definition of class `Person`.

Comment: I can't! It is not "Person" in fact, it's another class in a DLL, but this shouldn't important?

Comment: `person` is being explicitly cast as `Person` then implicitly cast to `Student` (During the `=` assignment). I believe you meant to explicitly cast straight to `Student`

Comment: A `Student` is a `Person` but the opposite is not necessarily true - a `Person` is not always a `Student`. That is why your cast is failing.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot convert a `Person` to `Student` directly.

Inheritance in OOP comes with `hierarchy level`, i.e. you can cast the `derived` class to `base` class, but the `opposite is not possible`. `You cannot cast base class to derived class`

One possible solution is :

Create `Student` from Person using `constructor overload`.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public Person(string fname, string lname)
    {
        FName = fname;
        LName = lname;
    }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public Student(Person person, string code)
        : base(person.FName, person.LName)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public Student(Person person)
        : base(person.FName, person.LName)
    {

    }

    public string code { get; set; }
}



static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person("Paul", "Catch");

        // create new student from person using 
        Student student = new Student(person, "1234"); 
        //or
        Student student1 = new Student(person);
        student1.code = "5678";

        Console.WriteLine(student.code); // = 1234
        Console.WriteLine(student1.code); // = 5678
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use a copy constructor like this to create a new instance of `Student` from a `Person`. You can't *extend* Person.

Comment: can I use a "generic" base? Because Person come with more than 20 properties...which is terrible write ALL

Comment: @paizza - and how can `Generic` help you to deal with 20 properties?

Comment: @paizza - Generic is much like creating Template, even if you use generics you have to deal with 20 properties.

Comment: I mean, extend "ALL" there is in the extended class...

Comment: @paizza - can you be a little more specific about "ALL"?

Comment: If I have a class with 20 fields (Name, Surname, Age, Date, and so on...) can't pass to the base constructor ALL of them (else, why I should use this? I just create a new class... stop). I just need to "copy the actual class adding a new custom field", without copy and paste :) Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @paizza - follow `poitroae` answer! you can create student class directly!

Comment: Yes I can create directly, but there I need to pass 20 value when I create it. I won't this...

Comment: @paizza - if you have 20 property you have to deal with it one way or another, i can suggest you to check Dictionary<string, object> it can be used to hold property!

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question! Suppose I have a List of Person (each person have 20 fields). I iterate it, and for each I add a new custom value). So, in the foreach, I won't to copy the Person single field and paste it. Just "extend" the Person one. Couldn't be so difficult?

Comment: I opened a new question. With a more precise example.

Answer (score 5):

Assign a `Student` to your `Person`.

```
Person person = new Student("Paul", "Catch");
Student student = (Student)person;
student.code = "1234";
```

Note that this makes all the casting pretty useless, better is:

```
Student student = new Student("Paul", "Catch");
student.code = "1234";
```

Comment: But I must to start having an istance of Person, not of student :)

Comment: Your cast needs to be to `Student`, not `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Student` class, add this constructor, assuming you have a constructor that takes two strings in the `Person` class

```
public Student(string val1, string val2) : base(val1, val2) { }
```

then you can use it like this

```
Student student = new Student("Paul", "Catch");
student.code = "1234";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is that in your assignment, you're trying to downcast Person to Student. This isn't possible, because the object is a Person, and the Person type has no knowledge of Student.

My interpretation of it is that objects have a specific type, regardless of how you cast it. A cast (like the way light is cast on an object) just dictates how you see that object. In the example case, a Person has no knowledge of a Student, therefore no matter how you look at it, you can't assign it to student.

A Student object, however, can be upcast to a Person, since every Student is a Person. You can always upcast to base classes, but you can't always downcast to derived classes.

I hope this gives you some clarity. (I also hope I got this totally right.)

Comment: Yes, but how can I upcast Student taking an intance of Person? In fact I already have an instance with Person, with the business data linked to it. I'd like to make a "copy" of Person and extend it...

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion is incorrect, a person can become a student (Not the other way round)

Change to:

```
Student student = (Student)person;
```

Although your type cast can be avoided ..

```
Person person = new Person("Paul", "Catch");
Student student = (Person)person;
student.code = "1234";
```

Becomes ....

```
Student student = new Student("Paul", "Catch");
student.code = "1234";
```

Comment: as I said, I got the same error

Comment: Yes man, but I don't create "Person", I already have it (it become with more than 20 properties, so I want create a new one copy them one by one). I just need to "extend" 1 properties in a class